# Searching for the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to compare which `div` in an orderd list is the one clicked.
Because I then need to show another `div` which has the index in a different list.

Everything's properly written, but the comparison is failing (`if (ten == $(this))`). (Now is chenged for: if (ten.is(this)) {. Works fine)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divs2 .os").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });
  var wybrany;
  $(".bt-o").click(function() {
    $(".divs2 .os").each(function() { $(this).hide(); });
    var ten = $(this);
    $(".divs .bt-o").each(function(e) {
      if (ten.is(this)) {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(themes/o2.png)');
        wybrany = e;
      } else {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(themes/o1.png)');
      }
    });
    $(".divs2 .os").each(function(e) {
      if (e == wybrany)
        $(this).show();
    });
  });
});
// EXTRA ADD FOR YOUR HELP (script for next & prev
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().fadeIn("slow").prev().fadeOut("slow");
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().fadeIn("slow").next().fadeOut("slow");
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.bt {
 position:absolute;
 left: 60px;
}
.bt-o {
 padding:35px 50px;
 width:54px;
 height:29px;
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: black;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.last {
 position:absolute;
 left: 1000px;
 background-image:url('themes/o22.png');
}
.os {
 position:relative;
 left: 30px;
 top: 75px;
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linia">
<a id="prev">PREV</a>
<div class="divs">
    <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2007</a><a class="bt-o">2008</a><a class="bt-o">2009</a><a class="bt-o">2010</a></div>
    <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2011</a><a class="bt-o">2012</a><a class="bt-o">2016</a></div>
    <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2000</a><a class="bt-o">2001</a></div>

</div>
<a id="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
<div class="divs2">
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2007</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2008</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2009</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2010</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2011</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2012</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2016</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2000</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2001</div>sample</div>
</div>
```

For Your help I added full working scripts if someone need to use feel free.

Comment: Are you sure you do include jQuery in your html? From the error running your script, it looks like you don't... :-(

Comment: Yes, me earlier function works fine, I checked all, and only this not work: if ( ten == $(this) ). I don't have any idea how compare with one is clicked

Comment: Strange, $ is defined in jquery.js...

Comment: Any special reason why `2000` and `2001` have their own `div.bt` wrapper in `div.divs`? If they were all in the same `div.bt` you could grab the corresponding `.os` element easily with [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: @MarcoS It was only missing in the snippet

Comment: @Andreas You can see here: http://ciemniak.com.pl/www/str3/index.php?page2=O_nas

Comment: With a slightly different markup it would be really easy: https://jsfiddle.net/uLLd9h5n/

Comment: @Andreas it's not work for second line :(

Comment: I've added an answer with some comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead of `==` to test the equality of two elements.

If you simply try to compare `ten` to a newly-constructed jQuery object around `this`, the comparison will fail -- they are distinct objects, created at different times.

`is()` does a *logical* comparison of two objects -- do they represent the same DOM element? That's why you don't need to wrap `this` in `$()` before comparing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divs2 .os").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });
  var wybrany;
  $(".bt-o").click(function() {

    var ten = $(this);
    $(".divs .bt-o").each(function(e) {

      // test for DOM equality with is()
      //
      if (ten.is(this)) {     
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        wybrany = e;
      } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
      }
    });
    $(".divs2 .os").each(function(e) {
      if (e == wybrany)
        $(this).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bt-o {
  margin: .25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linia">
<a id="prev"></a>
<div class="divs">
    <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2007</a><a class="bt-o">2008</a><a class="bt-o">2009</a><a class="bt-o">2010</a><a class="bt-o">2011</a><a class="bt-o">2012</a><a class="bt-o">2016</a></div>
    <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2000</a><a class="bt-o">2001</a></div>
</div>
<a id="next"></a>
</div>
<div class="divs2">
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2007</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2008</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2009</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2010</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2011</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2012</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2016</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2000</div>sample</div>
 <div class="os"><div class="rok">2001</div>sample</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need for `.is()` in this case: `var ten = this;` and then `if (ten === this)`

Comment: "Use .is() instead of == " Why? (Hint: for the benefit of the asker and future readers)

Comment: Added that. And yes, Andreas's approach would work fine -- but the `is`/`==` distinction seemed worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an id or any attribute for each div and adjust a little bit your code like this:

//id could be repleace by attribute what you set
if (ten.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id'){
     ........
}

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the structure of `div.divs` so that all `div.bt`s are in the same `div.bt` then this would be really easy :)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".bt").on("click", "a", function(e) { // add a click handler on div.bt which only executes the function if the clicked element has the class "bt-o"
                                          // https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

    var os = $(".os"); // get all elements with class "os"
    os.hide();         // hide all of them

    var clickedElementIndex = $(this).index(); // get the position of the clicked element relative to its sibling elements
                                               // https://api.jquery.com/index/

    os.eq(clickedElementIndex) // get the "os" element at the same position as the clicked "bt-o" element
                               // https://api.jquery.com/eq/
      .show(); // and show it
  });
});
```

```css
/* this rules are only for visual effects :) */
.bt-o {
  border: solid 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.os {
  display: none;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linia">
  <a id="prev"></a>
  <div class="divs">
    <div class="bt"> <!-- only one div.bt for all the a.bt-o -->
      <a class="bt-o">2007</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2008</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2009</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2010</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2011</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2012</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2016</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2000</a>
      <a class="bt-o">2001</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="next"></a>
</div>
<div class="divs2">
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2007</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2008</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2009</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2010</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2011</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2012</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2016</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2000</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os"><div class="rok">2001</div>sample</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler method with a little less code, you don't need the event handler e, :

```js
$(".bt-o").on('click', function() {
  $(".bt-o").css({  background: 'transparent'  }); // clear all backgrounds
  $(this).css({  background: '#f90' }); // colour this one

  var info = $(this).text(); // get the click text

  $('.os').hide(); // hide everything
  $('.os').each(function() { // cycle through everything
    if ($('.rok', this).text() === info) { // check each targets text
      $(this).css({
        background: '#bbb'
      }).fadeIn('fast'); // colour and reveal
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.bt {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bt-o {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.os {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #09f;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.os div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divs">
  <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2007</a><a class="bt-o">2008</a><a class="bt-o">2009</a><a class="bt-o">2010</a><a class="bt-o">2011</a><a class="bt-o">2012</a><a class="bt-o">2016</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bt"><a class="bt-o">2000</a><a class="bt-o">2001</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="divs2">
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2007</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2008</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2009</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2010</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2011</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2012</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2016</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2000</div>sample</div>
  <div class="os">
    <div class="rok">2001</div>sample</div>
</div>
```